# I would like to make a copy of my return, but i've already sent it. Can I pull up the return I sent and make a copy of it?

Tags: united-states

l'd like to make a copy of my return, but i've already sent it. Can I pull up the return I sent and make a copy of it?

Comment: How did you file your return, via mail or e-file, if e-file, which service did you use?

Comment: What do you mean "pull up"?  If you're able to pull it up, it would seem you already have a copy (possibly an electronic copy, but still).

Comment: You can get "copies" of your return from the IRS (some time) after it has been processed.  They are not actual copies (or weren't a decade ago), but rather printouts of the information on them.  See the IRS web site: https://www.efile.com/tax-return/tax-return-copy/

Comment: @jamesqf: that website is not the IRS, and you _can_ get from the IRS (for several years at least) a transcript for free _or_ a copy of the actual return for $50 no matter how or through whom you filed. But if you used any kind of preparer you _should_ be able to get a copy from them, usually free, including the company you link.

Answer (score 1):

If you used a website or software to complete your return there should be a way to print the return. This can be to review the return prior to filing, or to have a copy of the return for your records.

I have found it invaluable to have a PDF version of the return, because there are occasions where I want to reference a value without having to go through the website/software. I have found that it is nice to have two PDF files for each return. The first only includes what was sent to the tax authorities, the other has every worksheet that was used. This second bigger PDF includes dozens of pages that the IRS never sees, it has every "worksheet" that was used to calculate values.

You also want to have the file that the tax software used. This can be used next year as a starting point for the return. The major software packages can read each others files.

If you didn't use a website or software to complete the return but you instead went to a physical office they should have given you a computer file with your return. If you don't have it, contact them.